# Не удается подключить базу данных к серверу

Tags: java

Не удалось подключить базу данных Postgres к серверу Tomcat 10.0.27. Вот код DBConnection:

```
public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection getConnectionToDatabase() {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hplus", "postgres", "");
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection made to DB!");
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Вот код, где я пытаюсь получить соединение:

```
public class ApplicationDao {

    public List<Product> searchProducts(String searchString) {
        Product product = null;
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();

            String sql = "select * from products where product_name like '%"+searchString+"%'";

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while(set.next()){
                product= new Product();
                product.setProductId(set.getInt("product_id"));
                product.setProductImgPath(set.getString("image_path"));
                product.setProductName(set.getString("product_name"));
                products.add(product);

            }

        }
        catch(SQLException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return products;
    }

}
```

Вот что я получаю:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connection" is null
```

Я попытался отладить код, в логах появляется следующая ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.jdbc.Driver

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.jdbc.Driver
    com.example.demo.dao.DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase(DBConnection.java:14)
    com.example.demo.dao.ApplicationDao.searchProducts(ApplicationDao.java:19)
    com.example.demo.servlets.SearchServlet.doGet(SearchServlet.java:30)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1449)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376)
    com.example.demo.dao.DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase(DBConnection.java:12)
    com.example.demo.dao.ApplicationDao.searchProducts(ApplicationDao.java:19)
    com.example.demo.servlets.SearchServlet.doGet(SearchServlet.java:30)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Добавил dependency в pom, также создал дирекорию lib в папке WEB-INF и добавил туда postgres.jar, также добавил postgres.jar в директорию tomcat/lib/, но ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему в качестве драйвера для постгреса ваш код пытается загрузить явно "учебный" класс `com.example.jdbc.Driver`.

Попробуйте по старинке загрузить конкретный класс JDBC драйвера, для постгреса это `org.postgresql.Driver`:

```java
public class DBConnection {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

Также можно попробовать отменить регистрацию "учебного" драйвера:

```java
static {
    java.util.Enumeration<Driver> drivers =  DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver bad = drivers.nextElement();
        if (bad.getClass().getName().equals("com.example.jdbc.Driver")) {
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(bad);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not deregister com.example.jdbc.Driver", e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```